# regex to match string dot UPPERCASE then space

Tags: regex

I have string some like this:

Hello world.THIS is just a sample.TEXT to test. How it looks like

From this string I need to find **[dot]+[uppercase word][space]** there is no space between dot and uppercase word.

it must check if all characters of the word is capital, not only the first character.

I have this, but incomplete.

```
\.[A-Z]+
```

Comment: Yes, and what is the problem? It is [matching](https://regex101.com/r/31VA4I/1) `.THIS` and `.TEXT`. Use a capturing group to get the text without `.` - [`\.\s*([A-Z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/31VA4I/2). Or `(?<=\.)[A-Z]+`. Or `\.\s*\K[A-Z]+` - something from this must help.

Comment: Just add an empty space on the end of the regex. You already have everything else covered...

Comment: it should check if all characters of the word is capital, not only the first character. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Like [`\.[A-Z]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/31VA4I/3)?